# How to combine two dataframes from bank accounts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which contain transactions from two bank accounts. I would just like to combine them into one dataframe.  However this is not working well for me. The dataframes are called `df` and `JLcard` and here is some information

```
df.shape
(1405, 3)

JLcard.shape
(96, 3)

df.columns
Index([u'Transaction_Type', u'Transaction_Description', u'transaction'], dtype='object')

JLcard.columns
Index([u'Transaction_Description', u'transaction', u'Transaction_Type'], dtype='object')
```

So the two dataframes have the same column names, if in different orders.

There are also both indexed by date.

```
df.head(3)
Transaction_Type    Transaction_Description transaction
date            
2017-05-26  BGC UNIV    2997.71
2017-05-30  FPO PT  -2650.00
2017-05-30  SO  NS  664.00

JLcard.head(3)


Transaction_Description transaction Transaction_Type
date            
2017-12-11  MW  128.23  Js card
2017-12-12  WW  179.47  Js card
2017-12-13  XW  42.00   Js card
```

To combine them into one dataframe, I tried `pd.concat([df,JLcard])` which gives me:

```
 FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=True'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass sort=False

  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

The resulting dataframe is also not sorted by index. E.g.

```
    Transaction_Description Transaction_Type    transaction
date            
2018-04-10  ES  DEB -16.57
2018-04-04  OR  Js card 109.30
2018-04-05  WR  Js card 125.00
```

> Why does it say the "non-concatenation axis is not aligned"? Why does
>   it say it is sorting when it doesn't seem to be? And what could I do
>   to avoid the warning?  I simply want to copy all the rows from one
>   into the other and sort by the index (which is the date).

Comment: `axis = 1` looks to join the two dataframes by adding new columns. Since they have the same column headers, I think you just want `pd.concat([df,JLcard])` to add new rows

Comment: @ALollz That gives me "FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=True'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass sort=False

  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel."

Comment: @ALollz And then the dataframe is not sorted by the index.  (I edited the question. Thank you)

Comment: You can sort the index too. `df = df.sort_index()`. Does that combined with the concatenation work? Not sure about the sorting warning, perhaps set `sort=True` in the concat to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pd.merge(f,JLcard,left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: Will that just copy the rows as is or will it try to combine the rows somehow? I just want the rows copied over and put in the same dataframe.

Comment: This will merge the two dataframes based on indexes. But since you want JLcard essentially appended to df, I would first standardize the column names by making sure they match up in spelling and index order (use `df.sort_index()`) and then use `pd.concat([df,JLcard])` as previously mentioned by @ALollz. This will copy the rows.